# What lengths of coaxial feed lines should you avoid?

Tags: antenna-system

Are there lengths of feed line to avoid or ones that may cause problems with an antenna system? For single band use.
Appendix: The run of coaxial will be for the 10 metre band. I would imagine this has no or little relevance as lengths can be expressed in a manner for any desired frequency.

Comment: May I know the frequency band you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your antenna system relies on common-mode radiation of the feedline (most do not [when properly installed](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/538/using-a-balun-with-a-resonant-dipole)), feedline length is irrelevant to the operation of the antenna. So, the usual approach is to make the feedline as short as possible (possibly with a short loop somewhere, for future maintenance) since a shorter length minimizes losses and cost.

See also [Is there an optimum Antenna Feedline Length for mobile installations?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/is-there-an-optimum-antenna-feedline-length-for-mobile-installations)